# Looking for ideas with SQL query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

!!! ---------------------!!!

After exchanging some comments with people, I have decided to include the source data, so anyone who wishes to help with solving this could load it into a table and run the query.

Here is the link that retrieves data from Yahoo Finance for symbol SPY in csv format.

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/SPY?period1=1584963550&period2=1616499550&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true

The file header needs to be changed. Change Date to Source_Date and Adj Close to Adj_Close. The file does not have a Symbol column, so the query doesn't need to reference it. The only two relevant columns are Source_Date and Adj_Close.

!!! ---------------------!!!

The issue with my query is that it takes a very long time to run. The query is not wrong. I know exactly why it takes such a long time to run. I just couldn't come up with anything more efficient.

First, here is the business logic.

Let's say I bought Apple stock and it went down. It's been 10 days since I bought it and it is still down. I extracted an entire history of daily prices for Apple going back to 1993, and I uploaded it into a database table. Now I want to write a query that will tell me how often did Apple stock price recovered in more than 10 days.

For example. I bought Apple at $100. It went down to $90. It's been 10 days since I bought it. I run my query and it comes back with something like this:
-- Buy Date: April 1, 2001. Buy price: $10. Recovered on: April 12, 2001. Days to recovery: 12
-- Buy Date: June 12, 2006. Buy price: $23. Recovered on: July 20, 2001. Days to recovery: 38
-- Buy Date: January 15, 2009. Buy price: $65. Recovered on: December 30, 2010. Days to recovery: 700

Each example indicates that on each day between Buy Date and Recovered on date, the price stayed below the buy price.

My query has two steps.
The first step. Join the same table to itself, qualified as x and y. For each x.record it searches for the next minimum date where y.price is higher than x.price.

The second query will simply extract only those records from the first query result set where the difference between x.date and y.date is greater than 10.

The reason why the first query (see below) runs for such a long time is because for each record in x.table the query must search an entire y.table. That's a lot of table scans. It comes back with the result but it takes between 50 and 60 seconds.

The table stricture is very simple: Symbol, Date, and Price. Symbol and date are primary key.

```
SELECT  x.Symbol,
        x.Source_Date as 'Source_Date',
        min(y.Source_Date) as 'Recovery_Date'
  FROM  transformed_source x,
        transformed_source y
where   x.Symbol = 'AAPL'
  and   y.Symbol = x.Symbol
  and   y.Source_Date > x.Source_Date
  and   y.Adj_Close > x.Adj_Close
group by x.Symbol, x.Source_Date
```

*** Note This query will miss records where the price never recovered, so I will need to modify it with an outer join. It wouldn't make any difference. Changing it to outer join will not make it run any faster. So, working with this.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: I was looking for a solution, not a tip.

Comment: (Suitable tags would help bring appropriate people to your Question.  `[sql]` is far too generic to get much useful traffic.)

Comment: @Rick I have a very straightforward query, but it's the nature of that query (scans of an entire table for each row of the same table) that makes it run too slowly. I need suggestions to either how to rewrite it or to come up with a different solution. It's just a matter of optimization. I can't really think of any other tag I could have added to bring more traffic.

Comment: @Jake - `MIN` can be a point query, not a scan, if done right.  Gordon's option probably works.

Comment: Ok, I don't know if anyone wants to go through the trouble of emulating my issue, but if anyone does, I am including more information in my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find that a correlated subquery is better:

```
SELECT ts.Symbol, ts.Source_Date,
       (SELECT MIN(ts2.Source_Date)
        FROM transformed_source ts2
        WHERE ts2.Symbol = t.Symbol AND
              ts2.Source_Date > t.Source_Date AND
              ts2.Adj_Close > t.Adj_Close
       ) as Recovery_Date
FROM  transformed_source ts
WHERE ts.Symbol = 'AAPL';
```

Then for performance, you want indexes on `transformed_data(symbol, source_date, adj_close)`.

Comment: Perfect. It took 0.2161 seconds to run. Didn't even need to add indices on symbol, date, and price. Thank you.

Comment: Since the `PRIMARY KEY` is already `(symbol, source_date)`, the suggested secondary index is unlikely to be used and/or unlikely to help much.

Comment: @RickJames . . . That actually depends if the `date` in the primary key is the same as the `source_date` in the query.`

Comment: Symbol and Source_Date are a primary key. After I accepted Gordon's answer I realized that it didn't help as much as a hoped. It made the query run a little faster, but it was still too slow for the front end. Interestingly, when I run it in phpmyadmin it returned slices of 25 rows per page almost instantly, but if I expanded it to show a full result set, it still took 40 seconds. I also tried using limit instead of min on sub-query but it still ran too long.

Comment: @Jake . . . With the correlated subquery, the data can be returned as it is generated (unless you add a `group by` or `order by` to the outer query).

Comment: @Gordon Change to correlated query definitely improved the performance. Thank you for that. But it's still running too slowly. How can I capture the data as it's being generated. Is pagination the only way or is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an RDBMS that provides pattern matching (e.g. Oracle with match recognise) then you can write a query which will do one pass of your table.
I've put together a [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2d361d3730f792782a851a5996f02408)